# SSH Github can't connect

Tags: ssh, git, github

I went away from Git for 4 months and now returned to it, using @Treehouse Git Tutorials.

I tried installing Git 1.7.9.1 but my computer Mac OSX is already installed V.1.7.5.4 from 4 months ago and I've tried ways to uninstall it from those I found online (`sudo rm`...etc) but failed to. So I went ahead with those @treehouse tutorials anyway.

After adding the ssh keys, I tried `ssh git@github.com` but received this instead.

> Identity added: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa)
>   PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Again, I tried various solutions I found online to try and solve the "PTY..." problem but still could not ssh `git@github.com` successfully.

Anyone knows why and how I may resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't push to GitHub on this box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495872/cant-push-to-github-on-this-box)

Comment: Read also [What to do about “PTY allocation request failed on channel 0”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844393/what-to-do-about-pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0)

Comment: I've read both and tried both but none solves the problem. I don't even get the "successfully authenticated" notice.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ssh -T git@github.com` instead. The PTY allocation isn't actually necessary, as decribed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844393/what-to-do-about-pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0#comment4084446_3844393).

Have you [verified your SSH keys](https://github.com/settings/ssh) since [the GitHub security bug](https://github.com/blog/1068-public-key-security-vulnerability-and-mitigation) last month?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to try to connect *interactively* (which is the default of the SSH command) to Github servers: this is just for Git. Use `ssh -T git@github.com` to check that your SSH settings are ok. The `-T` will tell the remote server that you do not want an interactive session. Check the man page for details.

Instead of following the long and error prone help page of Github for setting up SSH, you could have used my tool [`github-keygen`](https://github.com/dolmen/github-keygen) which is dedicated to that task.